# Цветной текст в python

Tags: python

Как вывести разноцветный текст в python 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цветной текст выводится так:

```
'\033[0m'
```

31-39 Цвет букв
41-49 Цвет фона
1-9 Шрифт и эффекты

Comment: Это платформозависимое решение, на Windows без colorama работать не будет.

Answer (score 4):

Зависит от того где этот текст будет выводится. Для консоли пробуй модуль `colorama`